# Update the values of a dataframe with use of an actionButton in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which the user  uploads a file (here I just put the `dt` in a reactive function) and from there he can choose which one he wants to display via a `pickerInput()`. If he selects the `value1` he should be able to update all of its values by multiplying all of them with the `numericInput()` `value1` and create a new `sliderInput()`. When I try to load the app I get : `subscript out of bounds`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
# ui object

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            pickerInput(
                inputId = "p1",
                label = "Select Column headers",
                choices = colnames( dt),
                multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
            ),
            numericInput("num", label = ("value1"), value = 1),
            #Add the output for new pickers
            uiOutput("pickers"),
            actionButton("button", "Update")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            
        )
    )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output) {
    dt<-reactive({input$button
        name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
        value1<-c(2,4,6)
        dt<-data.frame(name,value1)
        dt$value1<-dt$value1*isolate(input$num)
    })
    observeEvent(input$p1, {
        #Create the new pickers 
        output$pickers<-renderUI({
            div(lapply(input$p1, function(x){
                if (is.numeric(dt()[[x]])) {
                    sliderInput(inputId=x, label=x, min=min(dt()[x]), max=max(dt()[[x]]), value=c(min(dt()[[x]]),max(dt()[[x]])))
                }
                else if (is.factor(dt()[[x]])) {
                    selectInput(
                        inputId = x#The colname of selected column
                        ,
                        label = x #The colname of selected column
                        ,
                        choices = dt()[,x]#all rows of selected column
                        ,
                        multiple = TRUE
                        
                    )
                }
                
            }))
        })
    })
    
    
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `reactive` should still work fine. You get `subscript out of bounds` due to this section

```
dt<-reactive({input$button
    name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
    value1<-c(2,4,6)
    dt<-data.frame(name,value1)
    dt$value1<-dt$value1*isolate(input$num)
})
```

The last line of the expression will be returned by `dt()`. In this case that is `dt$value1<-dt$value1*isolate(input$num)` which silently evaluates to `dt$value1`, not a data.frame.  Try:

```
dt<-reactive({input$button
    name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
    value1<-c(2,4,6)
    dt<-data.frame(name,value1)
    dt$value1<-dt$value1*isolate(input$num)
    dt
})
```

Answer (score 2):

To use the user input data, it is better to move the `pickerInput` to server side.  Then use `observeEvent` to update the reactive data and assign it to reactiveValues dataframe. Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("inputp1"),
      numericInput("num", label = ("value"), value = 1),
      #Add the output for new pickers
      uiOutput("pickers"),
      actionButton("button", "Update")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
    )
  )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output) {
  name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
  value1<-c(2,4,6)
  dt<-data.frame(name,value1)
  
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=dt)
  
  output$inputp1 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "p1",
      label = "Select Column headers",
      choices = colnames( dt),
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$p1, {
    #Create the new pickers 
    output$pickers<-renderUI({
      dt1 <- DF1$data
      div(lapply(input$p1, function(x){
        if (is.numeric(dt1[[x]])) {
          sliderInput(inputId=x, label=x, min=min(dt1[[x]]), max=max(dt1[[x]]), value=c(min(dt1[[x]]),max(dt1[[x]])))
        }else { # if (is.factor(dt1[[x]])) {
          selectInput(
            inputId = x,       # The col name of selected column
            label = x,         # The col label of selected column
            choices = dt1[,x], # all rows of selected column
            multiple = TRUE
          )
        }
        
      }))
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    dt<-reactive({
      req(input$num)
      dt <- DF1$data ## here you can provide the user input data read inside this observeEvent or recently modified data DF1$data
      dt$value1<-dt$value1*isolate(input$num)
      return(dt)
    })
    
    DF1$data <- dt()
  })
  
  
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.This way does not display the initial sliderInput() with the initial values. They should be displayed as they are at first and then updated if needed.

Comment: @YBS a few suggestions: 1. instead of `observeEvent`/`reactive` I would use `eventReactive`, 2. I would name either the reactive or the actual data.frame differently than `dt` to not have both objects with the same name, 3. I would leave the `pickerInput` `p1` on the ui side, because ultimately a lot of `renderUI` can lead to a slow ui (of course not in this small example)

Comment: @starja, good points.  Initially, I did suggest eventReactive.  As the data was defined on the server side, I moved the pickerInput there.

Comment: my data is coming from an uploaded file and this is why I used reactive() in dt in the example. So in my original app everytime I add DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=dt()) I get:Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: Do that assignment in an observer as  `observe({DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=dt())})`